# List item Alignment

Tags: html, css, html-lists

[image]

```
<ul class="list-unstyled services_list">
{% for link in links('header').get() %}
    {% if (link.parent_id == 3) %}
        <li>
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
            <a href="{{ (count(link.children) > 0 ? '' : link.url ) }}">{{ link.title }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

code ^

How to align the excess content ?

Comment: Use the *arrow* as a `pseudo` element of your `li`

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `text-indent`

```css
ul {
  width: 100px; /* demo only */
  margin-left:30px /* demo only */
}
li {
  text-indent: -.5em
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="list-unstyled services_list">
  <li>
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
    <a href="">some text</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
    <a href="">some text very big text</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
    <a href="">some text</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
    <a href="">some text</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
    <a href="">some text</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think you need something like this:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jazibbashir/myYUh/190/

**HTML Code:**

```
<ul class="icons-ul">
  <li><i class="icon-li icon-ok"></i>Bulleted lists (like this one)</li>
  <li><i class="icon-li icon-ok"></i>Buttons</li>
  <li><i class="icon-li icon-ok"></i>Button groups</li>
  <li><i class="icon-li icon-ok"></i>Navigation</li>
  <li><i class="icon-li icon-ok"></i>Prepended form inputs</li>
  <li><i class="icon-li icon-ok"></i>&hellip;and many more with custom CSS</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
.icons-ul{  
    width:100px;
}

.icons-ul>li {
position: relative;
}

icons-ul {
margin-left: 2.142857142857143em;
list-style-type: none;
}

ul, ol {
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.icons-ul .icon-li {
position: absolute;
left: -2.142857142857143em;
width: 2.142857142857143em;
text-align: center;
line-height: inherit;
}

[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
display: inline;
width: auto;
height: auto;
line-height: normal;
vertical-align: baseline;
background-image: none;
background-position: 0% 0%;
background-repeat: repeat;
margin-top: 0;
}
```

Hope this Helps!